# MediatR PipelineBehavior is not triggered. Prism.Unity is used as the DI-Container

Tags: prism, unity-container, mediatr

I want to improve my WPF Prism App by using a MediatR Pipelining. But my Pipline "LoggingBehavior" ist not triggert.

The setup of the pipelin in the DI Contianer settings:

```
        containerRegistry.Register(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMediator, Mediator>();
```

My LoggingBehavior-class:

```
public class LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> _logger;

    public LoggingBehavior(ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Handling {typeof(TRequest).Name}");

        var response = await next();

        _logger.LogInformation($"Handled {typeof(TResponse).Name}");

        return response;
    }
}
```

My handler

```
public class GetImportProjectDetailsQuery : IRequestHandler<GetImportProjectDetailsRequest, GetImportProjectDetailsResponse>
{
    private readonly IImportRepository _importRepository; 

    public GetImportProjectDetailsQuery(IImportRepository importRepository )
    {
        _importRepository = importRepository; 
    }

    public async Task<GetImportProjectDetailsResponse> Handle(GetImportProjectDetailsRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       
     //some code

      return result;
    }
}
```

My Request Type looks like this:

```
public class GetImportProjectDetailsRequest : IRequest<GetImportProjectDetailsResponse>
{
        public string? Id { get; set; }
}
```

My call

```
 private async Task<GetImportProjectDetailsResponse> GetImportProjectDetails(string projectId)
    {
        var importProjectResult = await _mediator.Send(new GetImportProjectDetailsRequest {Id = projectId});

        return importProjectResult;
    }
```

Is there any mistake in my code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
 _serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    _serviceCollection.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));

    _serviceCollection.AddSingleton(_configuration);

    _serviceCollection.GetMediatRHandlerAndServicesFromModules(_configuration);

    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.BuildServiceProvider(_serviceCollection);
```

Method GetMediatRHandlerAndServicesFromModules() looks like this:

```
 public static void GetMediatRHandlerAndServicesFromModules(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //Pipeline
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ErrorBehavior<,>));...}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).